# Node Express Router can't get response params

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I can not retrieve route parameters with a simple express.Router() in an web app.

Here is a minimal example:

```
var http      = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();

app.use('/hello/:world', express.Router()
    .get('/', function (req, res) {
        console.log("hello : ", req.params); //
        res.status(200).send({status: 'success', params: req.params});
}));

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

I don't get any error, the `res.params` is simply empty when I try to reach:
http://localhost:3000/hello/100 for example.

Here is the response:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "params": {}
}
```

What I have tried so far is to set `express.Router({ params: 'inherit' })`
as told here: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2151#issuecomment-44716623 but it doesn't change anything.

And here is the manual: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Property `params` exists on `req` object but not `res`. You seem to have a typo.

Comment: you were right -> fixed. thanks.

Comment: Does this fix the issue of empty response?

Comment: No, but I found a working solution on an other page I never founded before on the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer:

The thing that finally worked for me, based on these:

API doc :http://expressjs.com/en/api.html
SO example: [Express Router undefined params with router.use when split across files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977253/express-router-undefined-params-with-router-use-when-split-across-files)

is to set `express.Router({mergeParams: true})`.

So:

```
var http      = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();

app.use('/hello/:world', express.Router({mergeParams: true})
    .get('/', function (req, res) {
        console.log("hello : ", req.params); //
        res.status(200).send({status: 'success', params: req.params});
}));

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

Is giving the following response over http://localhost:3000/hello/10

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "params": {
    "world": "10"
  }
}
```